# How do you get a list of invalid values from a decimal field in Db2?

Tags: sql, null, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I have an issue with a column having null values in a not-null decimal field. The issue arises when that column is used (like in a case statement), but not when I simply do a select * from.

The error it comes up with is SQL0802 type 6 - Numeric data that is not valid. I was able to find a few of them and fix it, but I would like to get a list of all of them from this very large table.

But again, any time I use it, it gives me the error. This is what I have been trying mostly:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT keycol_1, keycol_2,
        IFNULL(badcol, -1) AS badcol_tmp
    FROM mytable
) WHERE badcol_tmp = -1
```

(Note that the column should not have negative numbers, that's why I'm using -1 there). This gives the error listed above.

I have also tried

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE badcol IS NULL
```

which doesn't give me any results... No error, but no rows. But I have seen it be null from scrolling through all of the data.

How can I get the list of null values in badcol?

Comment: @mao it is a DDS, not DDL. It is 2S  0. It is not nullable because it's actually a part of the key. Can you please elaborate on "But how can you be sure of the query that ran?" All I did was a "SELECT * FROM mytable" and scrolled a whole lot until I found a null. Platform is i-series. I don't know the version/fixpack, and don't really know how to find it (I'm not sysadmin)

Comment: @TheLittlePeace: please show us the piece or code that raises the error that you are getting.

Comment: @GMB By company policy, I'm not allowed to give many more details like actual column names or live code. But the first code bit in my question raises the error. And in the end, the question isn't really about the error, I want to know how to view all of the rows with null values where they shouldn't be, so I can FIX the error by making them valid.

Comment: How are you deciding it is a NULL, do you mean spaces or other character or no character is visible on your display for such values?

Comment: @mao I'm going off of how ACS displays nulls, with a '-' in that field. And, when I do a DFU to view/fix the data, it is blank.

Comment: I would use DSPPFM command on a green-screen terminal to see if these are really nulls. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47820048/3175562 I suspect they are not, or `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE badcol IS NULL` would work just like you expect.

Comment: @Mike I just tried it and found one of the examples I have yet to fix - it shows up as nothing, which I presume is not null then? Most of the other records seem to default to 00, which according to your link is how nulls should look?

Comment: View it in hex mode also to be sure of the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't that the value is null, if that were the case, then

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE badcol IS NULL
```

would work.  The problem is that the data in the field isn't numeric.

If you're keeping your system up to date, then congrats!  IBM has added some [validation utilities](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/6174171) in the most recent TR's for 7.3 and 7.4.

Otherwise try the following (for a 2 digit zoned number):

```
select *
from mytable
where substr(hex(badcol),1,1) not in ('F','D')
      or substr(hex(badcol),2,1) not between '0' and '9' 
      or substr(hex(badcol),3,1) not in ('F','D')
      or substr(hex(badcol),4,1) not between '0' and '9'
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this Monday when I'm back in the office. As a side note, should I change the post since it's not actually a null value despite looking like one on the surface?

Comment: @TheLittlePeace - Whether to edit the question in this kind of situation (where learning a bit more reveals the originally worded question to be "wrong" in some sense) is kind of tricky business. You don't want to suddenly make the answer or answers not "match up with" the question, because that would make things more confusing and less helpful for future readers of this post. I've gone ahead and nudged the subject line in the right direction; but in my opinion, it would be best to leave the body text the way it is.

Comment: I'll have to have a word with our sysadmins, because our system is not up to date apparently :) the query you provided did work though. Thank you!